# Make Outlook Appointments and when adding optional members they want to show as free

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar

I create a lot of outlook invites as a coordinator and with that, I put my manager as optional on all the invites just in case something happens but my manager does not attend any of those meetings. My manager wants to receive the invites as a way of tracking the meetings.

Is there a way for me on my end to show free on his calendar without my manager to manually go into each invite and select "show as free".

Answer (score 0):

That's impossible. In any case, once the user receives any meeting  invitations, they will appear in the user's calendar.